# Upon running wp_insert_user() WP Keeps Saying user_login is already in the system when it isn't

Tags: users

I am needing to archive particular user accounts and create new ones using the original archived username, email, etc.

My plan is to first update the current account with modified user_login, email, etc.  I archive the old username, display_name by appending "archive" to it.  Before this I have taken the original user_login, etc. and stored them in separate variables, i.e.

```
$origlogin = $user_info->user_login;
```

and then

```
$archivelogin = 'archived-' . $origlogin;
```

and so on...

First I am updating the particular user with new "archived" data.

```
$sql = "UPDATE " . $wpdb->prefix . "users SET user_login = '" . $archivelogin . "', display_name = '" . $archivedisplayname . "', user_nicename = '" . $archivenicename . "', user_email = '" . $archiveemail . "', user_url = '' WHERE ID = '" . $theid . "'";
$wpdb->query($sql);
```

I have confirmed in the database that it has been updated and the user_login is now unique and different from the original user_login that was there previously.

However, when I include this in my script afterwards:

```
if(username_exists( $origlogin )) {
echo "it exists";

}
```

It prints out 'It Exists' and when the script continues and tries to now create a NEW user using the original user_login ($origlogin), it spits out a duplicate username error and won't insert it.

Which can't be possible as I have checked over and over that there isn't a duplicate username in the DB as I replaced the original one with the archived version (that appends the word archived to the user_login).

Is there something I need to flush from memory or something or some step I am missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Direct modification of WP database is a very bad idea. In your case, you have problem because you avoid caching. WordPress caches almost everything what is able to cache, and user data are not the exclusion. When you call `username_exists()`, it returns information from the cache, not from the database.

You should use `wp_update_user()` to update user data. It sends emails to users, however, on changing password and email. You can suppress this behaviour by filters `send_password_change_email` and `send_email_change_email` (just rturn false from your callback function).

The worse way is to flush user caches after modification of database fields. You can do it by calling `clean_user_cache( $user )`.